# Switch Case Statements do not operate when using GCC Arm compiler and optimization

Tags: gcc, arm, switch-statement

I am using the 2011 Q3 ARM GCC compiler with an ARM M0 platform. On my current application, if I do not use optimizations (compiling with -O0), my code is too large and doesn't fit. If I use any optimization (-O1, -O2, -O3, -Os), the SWITCH CASE statements do not work. I have validated the code inside this block is not getting executed as simple GPIO toggling operations are not coming through.

I read somewhere that any optimization from -O1 and above will have issues with goto code. However, I can't find the solution to this problem anywhere.

I also tried using the latest GCC ARM compiler, but my tools are not compatible with this release.

Any help on this matter is appreciated!

Comment: It is quite possible that the compiler decides you **GPIO** toggling is useless.  Do you use `volatile`?

Comment: proved an example please, with disassembly of the switch statement in question

Comment: Also, what is "2011 Q3 ARM GCC"? GCC has version numbers like 4.8.1. You are using some sort of pre-built version. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your source code like so: the code that you don't want to optimize (eg. accesses to the memory mapped regions like GPIO) and the rest of it.

After you compile each source file with a different optimization level, you will get a working version with the "fragile" code.

Then, when you will debug the code, you will work with an object (.o) file and compile the rest.